# How to properly setup git for multiple projects with shared code base?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, gitlab

I am creating a project where I have 2 repositories that belong to one single project. One of them is the admin part and another one is the main product. Besides, I have shared functionality and assets that are going to be used for both of them. Both admin and product repositories should have their own remote counterpart and both of them should be able to reuse the shared functionality, but none of them should be aware of the other project.

Here is my folder structure

```
.
├── admin
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── roulette
│   ├── public
│   └── src
└── shared
    ├── assets
    └── components
```

My goal is to make sure `admin` and `roulette` have their own separate remote repositories with the ability to get access to a shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `git submodule` to solve this problem.

Make `shared` as a submodule of other projects, so that they can synchronize recent updates of `shared`.

You can find more details in [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
Hope this will help you~~